# Why CSS File doesn't apply to the html in my project?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I don't know why external CSS file doesn't apply to the html file.

I'm now programming on the Cloud IDE(goormIDE - it's similar to C9). I wanted to link external CSS File to the HTML File on the web server using node.js. But it doesn't apply to the HTML.  I researched a lot, but can't solve the problem.

It has 3 main file (index.html, style.css, main.js) And They are in same folder.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YOONJONG</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >

    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="intro.html">INTRO</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="board.html">BOARD</a>
    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    <p>blahblah</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
a {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

main.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = http.createServer(function(request,response){
var url = request.url;
if(request.url == '/'){
  url = '/index.html';
}
if(request.url == '/favicon.ico'){
  response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
    return;
}
response.writeHead(200);
response.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + url));

});
app.listen(80);
```

Comment: is style.css in the same folder as index.html, or is it in a subfolder?

Comment: @zack6849 — The question says "It has 3 main file (index.html, style.css, main.js) And They are in same folder"

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The styles show up when I copy/paste your code and run it.

Comment: Does your style.css return a 404 in the developer tools? Can you see your stylesheet in your page source? Like Quentin, it works when I copy paste your code as well.

Comment: @Quentin - When I tried making 3 file on my desktop(not on Cloud IDE), It works well.

Comment: @Helenesh - No 404. I noticed that Chrome&Firefox load my CSS File. and When I give a little change(ex. space-bar), CSS Works! So Weird!!

Comment: Thank you all. I solve the problem by modifying main.js file!

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

`<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >`

to :

`<meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`

Comment: This would solve a Yellow Screen of Death error if they were using XHTML (they aren't) and they were using a browser which didn't recover from non-well-formed XHTML (and I don't think any of those are about any more).